# How to solve an equation with one variable in Python which has exponential and log functions?

Tags: python, typeerror, equation

I'm trying to solve the below equation to get the value of b

```
from sympy import symbols, solve
import numpy as np

b = symbols('b')
expr = (30*np.log(b)/2.549*0.665*(1.5-math.exp(-0.4*(b-1))))-50
sol = solve(expr)
print(sol)
```

but the error shows 'loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type Symbol which has no callable log method' in line 4

Comment: perhaps this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61211476/loop-of-ufunc-does-not-support-argument-0-of-type-float-which-has-no-callable-ex

Comment: Did you import math fn?

Comment: Yes i imported math function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from sympy import symbols, solve , exp, log, power

b = symbols('b')
system = (30 * log(b)) / (2.549 * 0.665 * (1.5 - exp(-0.4 * (b - 1))) - 50)
sol = solve(system,b)
print(sol)
```